# How to run elasticsearch as root inside docker?

Tags: elasticsearch, dockerfile

Here is my docker file:

```
 FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    RUN cat /etc/group
    RUN chown -R root:root /usr/share/elasticsearch
    RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch
    RUN ls -ltr /usr/share/elasticsearch
    RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch
    ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
    RUN yum -y update
    RUN yum -y install crontabs
    RUN echo  "root" > /etc/cron.allow
    RUN echo  "elasticsearch" >> /etc/cron.allow
    RUN echo "" >> /etc/cron.allow
    RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/cron.allow
    RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/cron.d
    RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/cron.d
    RUN chown -R elasticsearch /var/spool/cron
    RUN chmod -R 777 /var/spool/cron
    RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/crontab
    RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/crontab
    RUN chown -R  elasticsearch /etc/cron.d
    RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/cron.d
    RUN chown -R  elasticsearch /var/run
    RUN chmod -R 777 /var/run
    COPY ./purge.sh  /usr/share/elasticsearch
    RUN   touch /usr/share/elasticsearch/cron.log
    ADD ./cron /etc/cron.d/cron_test
    RUN chmod 0777 /etc/cron.d/cron_test
    RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/cron.d/cron_test
    USER elasticsearch
    RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron_test
    RUN chmod 777 /var/spool/cron/elasticsearch
    CMD elasticsearch
    USER root
    EXPOSE 9200 9300
```

I want to run elasticsearch as user root becuase `crontabjobs` are running as user root as well. When I build the docker file and run it with the command below, I get this issue:

```
212744798@GH71T8S2E MINGW64 ~/Documents/docke
$ docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" es
```

---

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2019-03-15T12:22:34,596][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [unknown] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        ... 6 more
```

How can I run elasticsearch with user root? Do I need to change any permissions?

Comment: If a program tells you that it cannot run as root, then you should believe the program, rather than trying to force it to do something that it clearly wasn't meant to support. You can switch between root and a user within a Dockerfile. And afaik, you can tell cron with which user it should run a job. Fix your Docker image to accommodate the program that should run there.

Comment: can we switch from one user to another in running docker container.If possible then how

Comment: Call `useradd` to create the user you want. Afterwards, use the command USER in the Dockerfile to switch for the subsequent commands. Or write to crontab the user which should be executing Elasticsearch.

Comment: @RolandWeber how does a program not support running as root? Root is a just user with all the privs.

Comment: @spinkus Please read the question. It contains this: `java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root` It doesn't matter how that was implemented.